# MySQL will select on single table at the time

Tags: mysql

**My problem:**

I have hundreds of threads each one trying to query one of following queries:

```
SELECT max(x) FROM table1
SELECT max(x) FROM table2
SELECT max(x) FROM table3
...
SELECT max(x) FROM table100
```

As every one of these queries works on different table, it should be run at parallel and done quick, right? But it works very slow. So I look into "show processlist" and notice that only one query is running at the time. As I refresh the command I see every select query takes about 2 seconds to complete while every other is "Sleep". At this speed mysql daemon won't keep up with application and will soon freeze (151 rows in show processlist, all in Sleep state)

How come? Why it's not working in parallel?

**My system:**

MySQL version is: 5.5.37-0ubuntu0.12.10.1

Its a desktop application in Java using library mysql-connector-java-5.1.22

Every thread opens its own connection to DB, accessing its own set of tables and there is about 150-230 threads running at one time.

**mysql settings:**

```
[client]
port        = 3306
socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock


[mysqld_safe]
socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
nice        = 0

[mysqld]
user        = mysql
pid-file    = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
port        = 3306
basedir     = /usr
datadir     = /var/lib/mysql
tmpdir      = /tmp
lc-messages-dir = /usr/share/mysql
skip-external-locking
key_buffer      = 16M
max_allowed_packet  = 16M
thread_stack        = 192K
thread_cache_size       = 8
myisam-recover         = BACKUP
query_cache_limit   = 0
query_cache_size        = 0
log_error = /var/log/mysql/error.log
expire_logs_days    = 10
max_binlog_size         = 100M

ft_min_word_len=3


[mysqldump]
quick
quote-names
max_allowed_packet  = 16M

[mysql]

[isamchk]
key_buffer      = 16M

!includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/


max_connections = 600
```

Comment: I little bit more context would be great, like what language are you using, what connection type you created, is there a connection pool or not is this a web application or a desktop application?

Comment: By the time you look that thread has already completed its job and is asleep

Comment: There might be a connection limit at work. Even though you open multiple connections you might be limited to one active. Check you DB and connector settings. Other than that, possibly the code that you use to open the connections is serializing the requests down to one. There could be multiple causes for that.